# toggle across tabs in shinyjs

Tags: shiny, shinyjs

im trying to invoke js across different tabs in shiny like the code below

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- tagList(
  useShinyjs(),
   navbarPage(
   "shinyjs with navbarPage",
   tabPanel("tab1",
         actionLink(inputId = 'link',label = 'Fast Forward')
         ),
 tabPanel("tab2",
         actionButton("button", "Click me"),
         textInput(inputId = "hello", label='',value = "Hello!")
         )
 )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$link, {
  runjs('$("#link").click();')
})

observeEvent(input$button,{
  toggle("hello")
})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the command is not going through, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this modified server part:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
            observeEvent(input$link, {
                    runjs("$('a[data-value=\"tab2\"]').tab('show');")

            })

            observeEvent(input$button,{
                    toggle("hello")
            })
    }
```

Comment: thanks for showing the tab show. i can use that also to autonavigate the ui :)

Answer (score 0):

i found the mistake.

i wrote

```
runjs('$("#link").click();')
```

instead of

```
runjs('$("#button").click();')
```